# Set background of boxes in boxplot to a specific color with gnuplot

Tags: colors, gnuplot

I've got the following data:

```
# id       min  1st quart     median  3rd quart        max          sum    std-dev name
  1    0.00029    0.02590    0.06331    0.12910    6.50177   1524.58705    0.13483 spec
  2    1.50041    1.59762    1.67226    1.79827   13.45151  26583.69935    0.48373 schema
  3    0.00206    0.01292    0.02505    0.09679  116.93156   5337.36854    2.06006 truss
```

And the following gnuplot script:

```
set terminal png enhanced background rgb 'white' size 1920,1200 font "Verdana 10"
set output "charts/summary.png"
set boxwidth 0.2 absolute
set title "Validating all data"
set xrange[0:4]
set yrange[0.00005:50]
set logscale y
set grid y

set tics scale 0
set xtics rotate by -45
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror
set border 2

set style fill solid 0.25 border -1
set style data boxplot


plot "data/summary" using 1:3:2:6:5:(0.6):xticlabels(9) with candlesticks title 'Quartiles' whiskerbars, \
         ''         using 1:4:4:4:4:(0.6) with candlesticks lt -1 notitle
```

The output of which looks like:

[image: Box plot]

The problem being that I can't figure out how to set the background color of the boxes in the boxplot. I can only seem to turn on and off the fill-in color by removing the `set style fill solid 0.25 border -1` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the name of keyword doesn't suggest so, the `linecolor` seems to affect the color of the boxes, thus for example:

```
plot "data/summary" using 1:3:2:6:5:(0.6):xticlabels(9) with candlesticks lc rgb 'blue' title 'Quartiles' whiskerbars, \
    ''         using 1:4:4:4:4:(0.6) with candlesticks lt -1 notitle
```